# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package while importing models from database

Tags: django, python-3.x, module, python-import, importerror

I am trying to pull the data from admin pannel.
But when i print the post object here,it throws the error.
I have tried almost every method but nothing seems working

**views.py**

```
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Mam


def index(request):
    question = Mam.objects.all()
    #question = get_object_or_404(Mam)
    context = {'latest_question_list': question}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Mam(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    {%for i in context %}
        <p>{{  i }}</p>
    {% endfor%}`enter code here`
</head>
<p></p>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show full exception trace?

Comment: Please update your question with the directory structure of your project and how you are running the server.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you might be running the python file directly. In order to properly import the django model, you should let the django server start.

See here for an answer to a similar problem : [Django Tutorial. No module named ‘**main**.models’](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-tutorial-no-module-named-main-models/2625)

Also, check there are no relative path in the part of your file that is executed directly.